# AWS Lambda, retries on timeout, Python SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I was trying to invoke a Lambda function through the Python SDK in a *synchronous* fashion in a Jupyter notebook.  An event I am sending is such that it takes more than the maximum possible timeout limit (15 min) to complete.

I noticed that the event *sometimes* (not always) is being re-sent to the lambda upon the timeout error. This keeps going on and on until I shutdown the lambda by setting its concurrency to 0.  This never happens if I lower the timeout limit (e.g., 10 minutes), meaning, the event is never being re-sent, there is only one invocation in the log, only one error and no activity afterwards.

What is going on? How do I rationalize these observations?

Comment: Hi, have you looked at setting a maximum retry allocation as well as configuration of a DLQ? More information here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-max-retry-attempts-event-age-asynchronous-invocations/

Comment: @mokugo-devops Yes, of course. But that applies only to asynchronous invocations in my understanding.

Comment: Alternatively can you try looking at putting it into a step function and invoking that instead?

Comment: @mokugo-devops thanks, I will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend turning on DEBUG level debugging and examining CloudWatch logs when you see it get executed more than once.  I've seen this sometimes, and when I do I usually see log entries that come from the SDK code itself that tell me it has some built-in retry logic that is executing.  If the call to invoke the lambda doesn't get a proper response, it may retry the call again--but it is possible the service received the original request and executed it, yet something went wrong with the response and so the caller re-at

Check out what is said at this link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/

> **Note**: API calls can take longer than expected when network connection
> issues occur. Network issues can also cause retries and duplicated API
> requests. To prepare for these occurrences, [your Lambda function must
> always be idempotent](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-idempotent/).
>
> If you make an API call using an AWS SDK and the call fails, the SDK
> automatically retries the call. How long and how many times the SDK
> retries is determined by settings that vary among each SDK.

That article has tips for troubleshooting or changing config settings.

Also see https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html

Comment: Great info, thanks so much - investigating. I will the question open for the time being in case someone else contributes.

Comment: Are you still waiting for more answers on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/), by doing this you can control the retry logic of Lambda and mark it as a failure.

IF your Lambda function is taking 15 minutes, determine whether you can break it down into smaller Lambda functions and invoke each of these in turn in your Lambda function.